# Unable to break out of loop appropriately and cannot determine why

Tags: python, break

I am currently working on a personal python project.  I am new to coding so I understand that there may be many other mistakes with my code.

In the code that I am writing, the user is given the option to perform a variety of actions.  Pressing 7 will allow the user to "reset" the code.  This just calls the function that everything is written in and restores all variables and lists to their default.  Pressing 6 is supposed to allow the user to "end" the program by breaking the while True loop the code is contained in.

The problem is, if the user has already reset the program, ending the program will not work on the first try.  The user must always attempt to end the program one more time than the program has been reset.  I want the end action to only require 1 attempt regardless of how many times the program has been reset.

Below I have entered only the code that is necessary to demonstrate this.

```
def robotTaskManager():

    #List of actions, must code in new actions if necessary (if/elif taskNum == index + 1)
    actions = [
        'New Task',
        'View Tasks',
        'Time Update',
        'Robot Update',
        'View Duty Roster',
        'End Program',
        'Reset Program'
        ]


    while True:
        for i in range (len(actions)):
            print(f'{i+1}: {actions[i]}')
        taskNum = int(input('\nWhat action would you like to perform? '))
        print()


        #End Program action, breaks the main while true loop.
        if taskNum == 6:
            endProgram = 'noEndInput'
            print('1: Yes \n2: No')
            while True:
                try:
                    if endProgram == 'noEndInput':
                        endProgram = int(input('\nEnding the program will erase all data.  Are you sure you want to end the program? '))
                    if endProgram == 1:
                        break
                    elif endProgram == 2:
                        print('\n> Ending the program has been canceled.\n')
                    else:  #Rejects all integers that are not 1 or 2
                        endProgram = int(input('\nPlease enter 1 to end the program or 2 to cancel: '))
                        continue
                    break
                except ValueError:  #Rejects all inputs that are not an integer
                    endProgram = 0
            if endProgram == 1:
                break



        #Reset Program action, resets all data to default.
        elif taskNum == 7:
            reset = 'noResetInput'
            print('1: Yes \n2: No')
            while True:
                try:
                    if reset == 'noResetInput':
                        reset = int(input('\nResetting will erase all data.  Are you sure you want to reset the program? '))
                    if reset == 1:
                        print('\n> Program has been reset. \n')
                        robotTaskManager()
                    elif reset == 2:
                        print('\n> Reset has been canceled.\n')
                    else:  #Rejects all integers that are not 1 or 2
                        reset = int(input('\nPlease enter 1 to reset or 2 to cancel: '))
                        continue
                    break
                except ValueError: #Rejects all inputs that are not an integer
                    reset = 0

robotTaskManager()
```

I have tried debugging this for quite some time now and I have been unsuccessful.  Please help me figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Instead, you posted 60 lines of code for a 10-line problem.  This is not useful to future visitors to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `break` only breaks out of the inner loop. Are you trying to break out of all loops? If so, just `return` from the function. Overall, the program structure is poor. Calling `robotTaskManager` recursively means your program can be crashed by a user who keeps resetting the program until the call stack blows.

Comment: You are using recursion inappropriately.

Comment: One way to avoid the recursion would be to create a variable like `done = False`, and then make your loop `while not done:` (and set its value to `True` inside the loop when you want to terminate it).

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that, instead of actually resetting the program, you recurred -- you call the main function from within the main function.  Yes, that means that you make your user break out of each call individually.

You need to refactor your code so that a reset reinitializes the existing program, rather than starting a new one.

Here is the basic logic.  You have an outer loop that continues as long as the user wants to stay in the program.  You have an inner loop that handles each new session (sequence of tasks).  The initialization code (reset) is between the two loops.

```
done = False
while not done:
    # initialize program
    reset = False

    #Keep looping for commands until the user wants to reset or quit
    while not (done or reset):
        ...
        if taskNum == 6:
            done = True
            ...
        elif taskNum == 7:
            reset = True
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As ggorlen mentioned, if all you want to do is end any further actions in the function you have, then replace your if tasknum == 6 with the following code:

```
        if taskNum == 6:
            return
```

That is it.  If the user enters 6, these lines will cause the program to return to the line just below the line in main that called it.

Comment: This returns to the line of code just after the line that called `robotTaskManager`, which is only in `main` if you're in the first call.  Otherwise, it returns to the recursive call under action `7`.  In short, this doesn't fix the problem.  The current code `break`s the loop, runs off the bottom of the function, and does a tacti return.